# RLlib: Using a CNN to train on a 2D grid environment

Tags: conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, rllib, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I’m a newbie to RLlib. I developed a few RLlib environments before and successfully used PPO to train agents on them.

Now I developed a 2D grid environment where agents roam around and conquer territory (basically mark some cells as belonging to them.)

I want the agents to train on it and I want them to have a CNN. I’ve never used a CNN with RLlib before so I’m looking for the most straightforward and simple way to do that. **How can I do that?**

Also: I was told I need to get the CNN shape to be in the shape of my observation space, is that true?